# Ubuntu 16.04 shutdown / power off problem

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have a problem with Shutdown, I tried to edit the grub file (`/etc/default/grub`) by `adding acpi=force` command but it did not work and always when I try to make a shutdown (`shutdown -h now`) it appears this screen

[image]

Comment: did you run `sudo update-grub` after adding `acpi=force`? This can be checked using `cat /proc/cmdline` on your running system.

Comment: yes, I did it severl times but the problem still the same @pim